# Give a message when clicking Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<html>
    <title>a</title>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#target").keypress(function(event) {
                if ( event.which == 13 ) {
                    alert("Enter has been clicked.");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="target"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

I want a message box to appear once I click enter inside the input box.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the **[jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Hello_jQuery)**:  *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready. To do this, we register a ready event for the document."* In there you find enough information (and example code) to get started.

Comment: The **`input`** element should not have a closing tag. The element is "self-contained" and should essentially be written as **`<input.../>`** or **`<input...>`**.

Answer (score 2):

```
  // DOM ready handler
$(function() {
    $("#target").keypress(function(event) {
        if ( event.which == 13 ) {
            alert("Enter has been clicked.");
        }
    }); // missing ")"
});
```

Also remember a doctype at the top.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and remove the closing input tag.

```
<input type="text" id="target">
```

As @David pointed out, there can be different results if you use `==` vs `===` for the equality comparison. In this case it won't make a difference, but for safety it's a good idea to generally use `===`, and use `==` when there's a specific type coercion you're wanting.

Comment: You should use a triple-equal sign for the `if` evaluation.

Comment: @David: Makes no difference since `event.which` always returns a number.

Comment: @user1600680 True, but the OP  is a novice in JS and it would help to show him appropriate practices. Besides, you should at least let him know that `===` exists.

Comment: @David: Updated to make note of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running before the `<input>` element exists. You can either use the domready event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#target").keypress(function(event) {
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
      alert("Enter has been clicked.");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Or just put that script tag later in the file, maybe just before the `</body>` end tag.

Comment: You should fix the syntax errors as well.

Comment: for clarity david you should use the full $(document).ready surely

Comment: @Paul I guess that comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @david absolutely (for someone who knows what it means) but to someone (obviously) a bit 'new' it would probably help them more ;)

Comment: @Paul I think it's better that they learn the more common syntax now, rather than get more confused later. I explained what it did in the text above.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/M8y5J/

- fix syntax errors
- load when [document is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (note multiple ways of doing this)
- [use `on()` to attach event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

### JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    $("#target").on("keypress", function(e){   
        if ( e.which === 13 ) {
            alert("Enter has been clicked.");
        }
    });
});
```

### Full HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#target").on("keypress", function (e) {
                    if (e.which === 13) {
                        alert("Enter has been clicked.");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="target" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why ur code does not work with me ?:\ ;/

Comment: The fiddle or the code sample? The code sample just shows a few of the errors corrected.

Comment: $("#target").on("keypress", function(e){   
    if ( e.which === 13 ) {
        alert("Enter has been clicked.");
    }
});

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use the `.keypress` shorthand though. `.on` is not a must (in this case).

Comment: it works perfect under fiddle but in my firefox not

Comment: @eawedat - I added a complete sample.

Comment: but why you need             $(function () {
 if you already have onPress ? because anyway the script will not load until you press and to press it takes time you cannot press until you see everything loaded.

Comment: @FelixKling - I know that `on()` isn't required in this case; I tend to use it with all my event bindings so that they are consistent.

Comment: @eawedat - You need to delay execution of the script until the DOM elements are present. Otherwise, $("#target") will return an array of zero elements.

Comment: I see , thank you Mr.Tim :) credits to you.

Comment: @eawedat: You should read the tutorial I linked to...